# How to loop through the error response from django rest-auth

Tags: javascript, reactjs, django-rest-framework

I'm trying to display the error response from Django into my react app. I am managed to get the errors but not able to display them.

[image]

What I have done so far to display the error message

```
        errorMessage = (<p className='login-error-server'>{
            Object.keys(this.props.error).map(function (key) {
                return <span>{key}</span>

            })
        }</p>);
```

Comment: Are you getting any error in that code? Or are you just getting password1 and username being displayed but not message

Comment: How did you get this error message? I am trying to console.log my errors (for example: ```"username": [
        "MyUser with this username already exists."
    ]``` but i don't know how... Any clues?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's edited code based on screenshot and limited info provided, let me know if this dont resolve your issue in which case please clarify if there are any errors faced with your code.

```
errorMessage = (<p className='login-error-server'>{
  Object.keys(this.props.error).map(function(key) {
    return <span> { key } : { this.props.error[key].join(',') } </span>
  })
}</p>);
```

Answer (score 0):

By doing this,

```
<span>{key}</span>
```

You are actually printing `key`'s of object i.e. `password1` and `username`.

Each `key` in your `object` contains `array`. You need to again iterate over your `key`'s to get actual error messages,

```
<p className='login-error-server'>{
     Object.keys(this.props.error).map((key)=> {
          return this.props.error[key].map(msg => <div>{msg}</div>)
     })
}</p>
```